# Error : A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper

I'm using Oracle Jdeveloper 12c.

I'm trying to deploy my java application as a jar file, The deployment process goes smoothly without errors but when i try o run the jar file i gt this error "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"

please help.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that your Java and javac versions are inconsistent. You can check `java -version` and `javac -version` respectively in CMD

Answer (score 0):

I am using eclipse, so write my procedure for eclipse.
First You should change the build path for for your project

right click >> build path >>select ==  configure build path >> Libraries >> edit >> Execution Environment >> select == JavaSE-1.8(jre) >> Apply >> Apply and close

also you go on
JRE System Library >> right click >> build path >>select ==  configure build path >> Libraries >> edit >> Execution Environment >> select == JavaSE-1.8(jre) >> Apply >> Apply and close

Answer (score 0):

Altough this question is already a bit older, I want to add some information since the problem seems to occur often and does not provide further information.

- Check that the jar was compiled with the same Java version that is used to execute it. (Like mengli mentioned check java and javac version in the command line if you build there or check the java version in the command line where you execute the jar (or the topmost java version in your PATH environment variable if you execute it via double click) vs. the version that you configured in your development IDE for the project/jar artifact.
- Make sure your topmost package does not start with "Java" and no class is named "Java".
- Check the contents of your jar and make sure that the folder hierarchy for class files resembles their packages (I did not know that and extracted dependency jars not into the root folder but into a subfolder - this leads to the JNI error!)